# Identifying polygon/point shapefiles in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

I have a script which performs various functions on shapefiles, most of which are **polygon-based**. However, some shapefiles are **point-based** and I have to specify where these files are by editing the script. Is there a technique in python which allows the script to identify which shapefiles are **polygons**, which are **points**, and run the necessary functions. I have provided a snippet (tested) of my script below which focuses primarily on polygon shapefiles and I have commented out the last line of code which includes the function I use for point shapefiles.

I am using QGIS 2.6.0.

```
##Test=name
import os
import glob
from os.path import expanduser
home = expanduser("~")

#   Folder path of the directory and the "Results" folder
path_dir = home + "\Desktop\Test\\"
path_res = path_dir + "Results\\"

def run():
#   Set directory and search for all .shp files
    os.chdir(path_dir + "Shapefiles\\")
    for fname in glob.glob("*.shp"): 
#   Clip .shp files with the polygon shapefile "Grid.shp" and save files to Result folder (How to specify this for polygons only?)
        polygon_output=processing.runalg("qgis:clip", path_dir + "Grid.shp", fname, path_res  + "/"+ fname)
#   (How to identify point shapefiles and run the following command?)
#        point_output=processing.runalg("qgis:distancetonearesthub", path_dir + "Grid.shp", fname, 'HubName', 0, 0, path_res  + "/"+ fname)
run()
```

---

---

I managed to get a working script (even though the entire code could be vastly improved!).

```
##Test=name
import os
import glob
from qgis.core import *
from os.path import expanduser
home = expanduser("~")

#   Folder path of the Results for shapefiles
path_dir = home + "\Desktop\Test\\"
path_res = path_dir + "Results\\"

def run():
#   Set directory and search for all polygon .shp files
    os.chdir(path_dir + "Shapefiles\\")
    for fname in glob.glob("*.shp"): 
        shapefile = QgsVectorLayer( os.chdir(path_dir + "Shapefiles\\"), fname, "ogr" )
        print shapefile.geometryType()

#   Clip .shp files with the polygon shapefile "Grid.shp" and save files to Result folder
        if shapefile.geometryType() == 3:
            polygon_output=processing.runalg("qgis:clip", path_dir + "Grid.shp", fname, path_res  + "/"+ fname)

#   Use Distance to nearest hub function on point.shp files with the polygon shapefile "Grid.shp" as Hub layer and save files to Result folder  
        if shapefile.geometryType() == 3:
            point_output=processing.runalg("qgis:distancetonearesthub", path_dir + "Grid.shp", fname, 'HubName', 0, 0, path_res  + "/"+ fname)
run()
```

Comment: Ref. this Stack Overflow question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25273987/how-to-get-shapefile-geometry-type-in-pyqgis) -- you're looking for [Geometry Handling](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/geometry.html).

Comment: Thanks for the links @Erica, it's great to see there's several methods to get the result I'm looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to open it as a `QgsVectorLayer`

```
 layer = QgsVectorLayer('/path/to/shapefile_folder/test.shp', 'test', 'ogr')
```

[QgsVectorLayer](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html) objects have a method called `geometryType`. If you call that method for your newly created layer :

```
>>> print layer.geometryType()
2
```

Where 0 is points, 1 is lines and 2 is polygons

Comment: Many thanks mate, I will attempt to incorporate this into the script and see how far I can get. Question: would the script open the entire file to see the `geometryType` or just the header as @GIS-Jonathan described? I do have a lot of shapefiles so I wonder if speed would be an issue here.

Answer (score 3):

I guess the "proper" way is to use QGIS' API which I'd hope would expose that. But I don't know how to do that.

---

An alternative is to look without the shapefile itself. The basics of the specification are on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile#Shapefile_shape_format_.28.shp.29

What you want is: `bytes 32–35` of the main header which dictates what the geometry type is. The values of this are integers and should be:

```
Value Shape Type
0 Null Shape
1 Point
3 PolyLine
5 Polygon
8 MultiPoint
11 PointZ
13 PolyLineZ
15 PolygonZ
18 MultiPointZ
21 PointM
23 PolyLineM
25 PolygonM
28 MultiPointM
31 MultiPatch
```

So all you need to do is parse the header of the file in Python to determine those.

For reference, the official Shapefile "Specification" (actually a white paper) is: http://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf

Comment: Many thanks buddy, I will look into this and see how 'easy' it is for me to implement it into the script.