# Getting random values from geometryType() in a standalone PyQGIS script

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, standalone

I am asking this question based on the result I received from this [earlier post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/124866/how-to-identify-polygon-point-shapefiles-in-python/124870#124870). The following script only works if I set `geometryType() == 3` as that is what is being printed out in the Python console even though @nickves from the previous post mentioned that 0, 1 and 2 are for points, lines and polygons respectively.

Could someone point out my mistake please? Feel free to cross this post over to Stack Overflow, I only posted it here as the script is based on geometry data.

```
##Test=name
import os
import glob
from qgis.core import *
from os.path import expanduser
home = expanduser("~")

#   Folder path of the Results for shapefiles
path_dir = home + "\Desktop\Test\\"
path_res = path_dir + "Results\\"

def run():
#   Set directory and search for all polygon .shp files
    os.chdir(path_dir + "Shapefiles\\")
    for fname in glob.glob("*.shp"): 
        shapefile = QgsVectorLayer( os.chdir(path_dir + "Shapefiles\\"), fname, "ogr" )
#      print shapefile.geometryType()
        print shapefile.wkbType()

#   Clip .shp files with the polygon shapefile "Grid.shp" and save files to Result folder
#        if shapefile.wkbType() == 2:
#            polygon_output=processing.runalg("qgis:clip", path_dir + "Grid.shp", fname, path_res  + "/"+ fname)

#   Use Distance to nearest hub function on point.shp files with the polygon shapefile "Grid.shp" as Hub layer and save files to Result folder  
        if shapefile.wkbType() == 0:
            point_output=processing.runalg("qgis:distancetonearesthub", path_dir + "Grid.shp", fname, 'HubName', 0, 0, path_res  + "/"+ fname)
run()
```

Comment: So, are you getting 3 as the geometry type of both point and polygon layers?

Comment: Hi @gcarrillo, yes I get `3` as the geometry type.

Comment: Strange @Joseph, I've just tested it and get 0 (point), 1 (line), and 2 (polygon). Can you tell me what you get when you run `myLayer.wkbType()` for the point layer which gives you `geometryType=3`? The list of possible values for `wkbType()` is [here](http://www.qgis.org/api/group__core.html#ga8da456870e1caec209d8ba7502cceff7).

Comment: Thank you @gcarrillo, I will give it another go and report back. I have moved on from this problem so it's not too important but would be quite useful to resolve.

Comment: @gcarrillo I still receive the same when using `myLayer.wkbType()`.

Comment: Could you please post somewhere the point layer that gives you geometry type 3 or tell me/us via a short code snippet how you are getting the geometry type for that layer?

Comment: @gcarrillo, done thanks. Whenever I run this, the values printed out are random and range from single digits (0 or 3) to (1345084765 or 777508536).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are facing is due to not valid layers constructed by `QgsVectorLayer()`. If you print `shapefile.isValid()` you will be getting `False` for all layers.

This happens because you need to set the QGIS prefix path and initialize `QgsApplication` before using `QgsVectorLayer` in standalone scripts/apps.

The solution for your problem is to:

- Add these two lines to your script (below the import section):

  ```
  QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr", True) # Adjust it to your path
  QgsApplication.initQgis()
  ```
- Adjust the arguments you are passing to `QgsVectorLayer` to:

  ```
  shapefile = QgsVectorLayer( path_dir + "Shapefiles\\" + fname, fname, "ogr" )
  ```

Now you could print the following layer properties and get appropriate results (0 for points, 1 for lines, and 2 for polygons):

```
print fname, shapefile.isValid(), shapefile.geometryType()
```

Comment: Great! @Joseph, do you agree to change the title to sth like "Getting random values from geometryType() in a standalone PyQGIS script"? I think the post could be more visible for search engines this way.

Comment: Agreed and done :)