# How to use `layer.getFeatures()` in a standalone script?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, standalone

I am following the [QGIS Cookbook](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html) and [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54057/how-to-read-the-attribute-values-using-pyqgis) where it concerns reading attributes from layers. I would like to exploit this method and implement it into a standalone script.

Essentially, I want to read the first feature of a shapefile from a field called `Rank`, take the value of this feature (all values in the `Rank` field are the exact same) and include it into a QGIS algorithm.

I wonder if there's an alternative to using `layer.getFeatures()` as, I believe, this is used with the canvas when QGIS is running. I have the following basic script but doesn't like `fname.getFeatures()`:

```
path_dir = home + "\Desktop\Test\\"
path_res = path_dir + "Results\\"

for fname in glob.glob(path_dir + "*.shp"):
    for feature in fname.getFeatures():
        fid = 1
        iterator = fname.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFid(fid))
        idx = fname.fieldNameIndex('Rank')
        Rank_value = idx[1]

        #Do some processing, finish with field calculator algorithm

        general.runalg("qgis:fieldcalculator", fname, 'Rank', 1, 10, 0, False, Rank_value, path_res + fname)
```

Is this the correct method or would it be much easier to *read* the `Rank_value` from a shapefile and *write* to another programatically?

---

**EDIT**:

Following @gcarrillo's answer, the script does not produce any results. I have modified the script to match the one suggested but not sure why no output files are produced.

To try and clarify exactly what I'm looking for:

1. A value from the `Rank` field of a shapefile is read.
2. A grid is created.
3. The same shapefile is clipped onto the grid (it would then have more polygons, thus more features).
4. The `Rank` field for this newly clipped shapefile is updated with the value read at the start.
5. Next shapefile...

   ```
   path_dir = home + "\Desktop\Test\\"
   path_res = path_dir + "Results\\"

   for fname in glob.glob(path_dir + "*.shp"):
       vLayer = QgsVectorLayer(fname,"any name","ogr")
       idx = fname.fieldNameIndex('Rank')
       Rank_value = vLayer.uniqueValues(idx)[0]

       outputs_1=general.runalg("qgis:creategrid", 1000, 1000, 24108, 18351.157175, 258293.802316, 665638.226408, 1, 'EPSG:7405', None)
       outputs_2=general.runalg("qgis:clip", outputs_1['SAVENAME'], fname, None)
       outputs_3=general.runalg("qgis:fieldcalculator", outputs_2, 'Rank', 1, 10, 0, False, Rank_value, path_res + fname)
   ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tested the following script on GNU/Linux, QGIS v.2.8.1, Processing v.2.6 and Processing v.2.9.1.

```
import sys,os,glob
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

app = QApplication([])
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr", True) # Adjust it to your path
QgsApplication.initQgis()

path_dir = "/docs/borrar/test/"
path_res = path_dir + "results/"

sys.path.append("/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/") # Where Processing is installed
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
from processing.tools import *

for fname in glob.glob(path_dir + "*.shp"):
    vLayer = QgsVectorLayer(fname,"any name","ogr")
    idx = vLayer.fieldNameIndex('rank')
    Rank_value = vLayer.uniqueValues(idx)[0] # uV returns a list, get the 1st element

    #Do some processing, finish with field calculator algorithm
    outputs_1=general.runalg("qgis:creategrid",1,"-956314.538361,3285493.72235,-53712.3143749,1885220.75154",250000,250000,None)
    outputs_2=general.runalg("qgis:clip", outputs_1['OUTPUT'], fname, None)
    general.runalg("qgis:advancedpythonfieldcalculator", outputs_2['OUTPUT'], 'rank', 1, 10, 3, False, "value=%f" % Rank_value, path_res + os.path.basename(fname))

QgsApplication.exitQgis()
```

As you can see, the syntax of the `qgis:creategrid` algorithm differs from your version and from the version we ran at [Import error for qgis.core when running OSGeo4w shell script](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129915/cannot-run-standalone-qgis-script?lq=1). Additionally, I ended up using the `qgis:advancedpythonfieldcalculator` algorithm, which provides a help.

Hope you can make it to work in your environment, pay attention to paths.

Comment: Modified your script to work with my environment and it works =). Thank you very much @gcarrillo! I have one minor question regarding the _advanced python field calculator_ algorithm: if a `Rank` field already exists, can it be updated by adding it to the formula (eg. `"value=%f(<Rank>)" % Rank_value`? If this requires a bit more code then I will research it before asking another question. Thanks again!

Comment: That's great! Regarding the question, I wasn't able to update a field. I'd have a look at the documentation of the algorithm or first try inside QGIS and see how the syntax looks like before writing it in a script.

Comment: Many thanks! This isn't really a necessity but I will look into the documentation and will try it inside QGIS. Fun to test out =). Will award you the bounty in 2 hours :)

Answer (score 4):

**For the first question:**

You need to create a `QgsVectorLayer` object from your Shapefile path. Only then you can access the `getFeatures()` function. That is:

```
for fname in glob.glob(path_dir + "*.shp"):
    for feature in QgsVectorLayer(fname,"any name","ogr").getFeatures():
```

**My recommended way of doing it**

You don't actually need to access getFeatures() nor to use a for. You can accomplish what you want with this code:

```
path_dir = home + "\Desktop\Test\\"
path_res = path_dir + "Results\\"

for fname in glob.glob(path_dir + "*.shp"):
    vLayer = QgsVectorLayer(fname,"any name","ogr")
    idx = vLayer.fieldNameIndex('Rank')
    Rank_value = vLayer.uniqueValues(idx)[0] # uV returns a list, get the 1st element

    #Do some processing, finish with field calculator algorithm
    general.runalg("qgis:fieldcalculator", fname, 'Rank', 1, 10, 0, False, Rank_value, path_res + os.path.basename(fname))
```

Since you'll be using `QgsVectorLayer`, don't forget to set the prefix path before initializing QGIS, as you did at [Getting random values from geometryType() in a standalone PyQGIS script](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/125127/getting-random-values-from-geometrytype-in-a-standalone-pyqgis-script/132338#132338).

Comment: Awesome, many thanks for this @gcarrillo! Not sure why but no output is being produced. All the prefix paths are set, testing this with a single shapefile but still no result. Strange, still testing this.

Comment: The error was on my part (ofcourse!), your script works great! Thank you very much =)

Comment: Urgh, my sincerest apologies. Initially, I thought the script worked but later noticed the times when the files were modified which didn't change when running the script. There are still no shapefiles being produced.